# HTML support in Header Footer for iText 7

Tags: itext, itext7

For iText 5, the following link can be used for html support:

http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/page-events/page-events-headers-and-footers#1331-htmlheaderfooter.java

For iText 7, the libraries have changed. Does someone know how to get it done for iText 7?

Code currently used:

```
protected class TableFooterEventHandler implements IEventHandler {
    protected ElementList header;
    protected ElementList footer;

    public TableFooterEventHandler() throws IOException {
        header = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(HEADER, null);
        footer = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(FOOTER, null);

    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = docEvent.getDocument();
        Document document = new Document(pdfDoc).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED);
        PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
        Rectangle[] columns = {
                new Rectangle(36, 36, 254, 770),
                new Rectangle(305, 36, 254, 770)};
        document.setRenderer(new ColumnDocumentRenderer(document, columns));
        for(Element e : header)
            document.add(new Paragraph(header).setFont(title ? bold : normal));
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamBefore(), page.getResources(), pdfDoc);
        new Canvas(canvas, pdfDoc, new Rectangle(36, 20, page.getPageSize().getWidth() - 72, 50)).add(header);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new HtmlHeaderFooter().createPdf(DEST);
}

public void createPdf(String filename) throws Exception{

    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4);
    doc.setMargins(36, 36, 72, 36);

    pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, (new TableFooterEventHandler()));

    for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
        doc.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
    }
    doc.add(new AreaBreak());
    doc.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
    doc.add(new AreaBreak());
    doc.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));

    doc.close();
}
```

In the line:

```
for(Element e : header)
```

Element has been deprecated. What is its corresponding for iText 7?

Comment: html2pdf for iText 7 is expected for early 2017.

Comment: To expand on Amedee's answer: the Element-class is used to repesent an Html-element and is defined in XmlWorker. The equivalent of XmlWorker for iText7 is currently known as Html2Pdf and is in development. A first version is expected in early 2017 :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm happy to inform that `pdfHTML` add-on for `iText7` has been released!
To convert an HTML snippet to a list of elements, use `HtmlConverter.convertToElements`, which is an `iText7` alternative of `XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList`.

Simple example when no additional `ConverterProperties` are set:

```
List<IElement> headerElements = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(html);
```

After that you can use those elements in whatever fashion you prefer, for instance adding them to `Canvas` like you wanted to do in your code:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(canvas, pdfDoc, new Rectangle(36, 20, page.getPageSize().getWidth() - 72, 50));
for (IElement headerElement : headerElements) {
    // Making sure we are adding blocks to canvas
    if (headerElement instanceof IBlockElement) {
        canvas.add((IBlockElement)headerElement);
    }
}
```